# Python-celery(v4.1.0) beat task failed to run with argument number error

Tags: python, celery

My intention is to extract task configuration form MongoDB to kick off my beat task export(args). But only got an error: `export() takes 0 positional arguments but 15 were given`, here's config file:

```
from celery.schedules import crontab
from exportUtils import MongodbUtils

broker_url = 'amqp://ops:123465@127.0.0.1:5672/tasks'
mongo_uri = "mongodb://task:task@localhost/task_config?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1"
beat_schedule = {}

client = MongodbUtils(mongo_uri)
tasks = client.find("task_config", "cron_tasks", {"is_enabled": True})
client.close()
for task in tasks:
    crons = task["crontab_string"].split()
    schedule = crontab(hour=crons[0], minute=crons[1], day_of_week=crons[4], day_of_month=crons[2], month_of_year=crons[3])
    beat_schedule[task["task_name"]] = {
        'task': task["task_def"],
        'schedule': schedule,
        'args': (task["args"])
    }
print(beat_schedule)
```

Task export():

```
@app.task
def export(paras):
    client = MySQLUtils(paras)
    cols, rows = client.execute_sql(paras["script"])
    export_to_xls(paras["output"], cols, rows)
```

I assume `args` in export() to be dict type and `beat_schedule` should be like below as I printed it out in my terminal:

```
{'test_demo': 
    {'task': 'tasks.export', 
     'schedule': <crontab: * */1 * * * (m/h/d/dM/MY)>, 
     'args': {'receivers': 'lizhi@qq.com', 
     'content': 'Welcome', 
     'output': 'export.xls'
     .....
    }
 }}
```

I have changed export(paras) into export(**paras), still no luck, anyone please help here? If any further info needed, also let me know. Thx :)

Comment: but, `def export(param):` don't need to be with `self` ? `def export(self, paras):`

Comment: export() method is not part of class, I think it's ok without self.

Comment: I converted args into one-element tuple and it solved...